# como mandar un parametro a una pagina web en php y que me regrese un json

Tags: php, webservice

Hola buen día tengo una duda soy novato en php y necesito mandar un parámetro a una pagina web la cual es la siguiente  
"http://hashtoolkit.com/decrypt-md5-hash/"
 mas el parámetro, que es un hash que obtendré de una de datos se podrá realizar 
esa especie de servicio web en php.

Comment: Se pueden pasar parámetros de manera diferente, va a depender de lo que tengas en mente. Lo más sencillo sería pasarlos en el GET haciendo algo como `miurl.com/carpeta/?parametro1=valor1&parametro2=valor2...`

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que no necesites autenticación, lo mas simple sería tener un index.php en http://hashtoolkit.com/decrypt-md5-hash/ y la consulta la podrías hacer por ajax o de manera directa, por ejemplo: http://hashtoolkit.com/decrypt-md5-hash/index.php?parametro1=valor&parametro2=valor (y sigue)...

En el index.php tomas los valores que esperas recibir.
Creas la conexión a tu base de datos, realizas la consulta, en un bucle vas recibiendo las filas y las cargas en un vector.
Este vector deberías de estructurar correctamente para que al final puedas retornarlo mediante la función "json_encode($vector)".

Un código extremadamente simple sería el siguiente:

```
// manejador de base de datos
require('db_api.php');
// recibo el parametro
$param1 = $_GET["parametro1"] ?? '';
// array para almacenar los elementos a retornar
$items = array();
// objeto con el cual manejo las consultas a mi tabla usuarios
$dbh = new DB_Usuarios_Tbl();
// esta función "setea" la consulta y limpia los datos recibidos
$dbh->leerDatos($param1);
// voy recibiendo las filas
while($row = $dbh->db_fetch_row()){
    $items[] = $row;
}
// retorno el resultado
print json_encode( $output );
```

Esto sería lo mas simple, lo ideal sería un servicio REST con autenticación. 
Hay librerías para eso.

Espero te sirva para tener una idea.

Comment: ok muchas gracias seguiré intentando